# How to completely remove my Emacs?

Tags: ubuntu, emacs, uninstall, apt-get, make

I downloaded Emacs source files, and installed it using `make`. After installing Emacs successfully, I manually removed the downloaded source files to save disk space. Now I want to remove Emacs and I tried to use `sudo apt-get purge emacs`. But it says Emacs has not been installed and will not be removed. But I can run Emacs by typing `emacs` in the terminal. Also the command `which emacs` shows the result `/usr/local/bin/emacs`.

Why can't `apt-get` detect it? How can I remove Emacs completely in this situation? My OS is Ubuntu 12.04, and my Emacs version is 24.3.1. Thanks.

Comment: apt-get will only detect emacs if it's been installed by apt-get. Why do you want to remove emacs now ?

Comment: @Lawrence: Because I am short of disk space and I decide not to learn emacs in the near future. Vim is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the source files again(same version), unpack and try

```
make uninstall
```

This should remove all files, which have been installed by your previous

```
make install
```

In general, you have to do symmetrical actions when installing and removing software packages.
apt-get can only remove packages which have also been installed with it. it does not know anything about your manual emacs installation.

Comment: Thanks. Good for removing completely and saving my efforts to search files to be deleted. Using `make uninstall` is the standard way to remove files.

Answer (score 0):

If you try `sudo make -n install`, where the `-n` option means that nothing will actually be executed, it will go through a dry run, allowing you to see what `make install` did when you originally installed emacs. You can then go through and manually remove what you need to.

Comment: Thanks. It's a good method. But that requires me to download source file and do `configure` and `make` again. A little inconvenient.

Answer (score 0):

Install `emacs` again under a different location, say `/tmp/emacs`, then just generate the list of files under that location and delete each corresponding location under `/usr/local`.

Comment: Good method. But like the one suggested by @denmch, a little inconvenient. Maybe I will choose to manually delete emacs-related files under the installation path. But Still thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove everything obviously emacs-related under /usr/local. If you use ls -lt to sort the file list by time it might help you to identify the files. In addition to the emacs executable, there is a directory under either /usr/local/share or /usr/local/lib.

Answer (score 0):

Actually we might use the command `locate emacs` in Terminal, then the Terminal will display a number of directories and files concerned with Emacs. But it is noticed that we shouldn't delete those directories and files whose name contains number `22` since they are related to the Apple native version Emacs, say `emacs 22.1` in my own macOS.

In general, it's enough to delete the `build directory` and `Emacs.app`. By `locate emacs` I found that almost all installed things related to the Emacs compiled from source code reside in the `build directory` (say `~/emacs`) and `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents`. Delete these two directories. It's done.

BTW: According to GNU Emacs manual (3.12 How do I uninstall Emacs?), it said:

> Emacs does not come with an uninstall program. No files are installed outside of the directories you find in the binary zip archive, so deleting those directories is sufficient to clean away the files.

But this `manual node` is written for the FAQ for using GNU Emacs on MS Windows. I have no idea whether or not it's appropriate for other OS, for example, the macOS or Linux.